# Mutex in C++ BEFORE C++11

Tags: c++, mutex, c++03

Question is simple - what are simple, ready-to-use solutions for mutexes in C++ before C++11 ? I need nothing fancy - just some bit of code to wait for another callback (that may happen anytime) to finish before executing.

I'm running on your everyday PC, i7 and whatnot. No specific performance requirements (simply not too slow), but must do the job of stopping one process and let the other finish and then resume the first one.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You would have to use some OS specific functionality, like pthreads, or try [boost.mutex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_types).

Comment: For what target system and processor do you ask that question? **Please edit your question** to improve it and motivate it.

Comment: Whatever API you are using to launch multiple threads should have its own mutex implementation already available.

Comment: I'm not the one creating the threads (I'm merely providing a thread-safe library which has some critical sections) but yeah I could ask whoever's gonna integrate my stuff to tell me what they're using for multi-threading on their side.

Comment: An everyday PC runs under *some* operating system (usually Windows, but could be Linux, FreeBSD or even FreeDOS). And that particular OS matters for your question. Without mention of your OS, the question is unclear

Answer (score 6):

[Boost Synchronization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html) is surely a valid option.

If you don't want to use Boost (based on your question you may find it overkill for your needs), you can write your own c++ class wrapper around the API provided by your target platform (i.e. [POSIX thread mutex](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html) for POSIX compliant platforms, or [Windows Mutexes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/windows/desktop/ms684266(v=vs.85).aspx) or [Critical Sections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/windows/desktop/ms682530(v=vs.85).aspx) on Microsoft Windows OS).

There are surely a lot of such wrapper class already implemented by someone else, i.e. you can try searching on GitHub using the mutex keyword and restricting results for code and C++ language ([here are a lot of results](https://github.com/search?l=C%2B%2B&q=mutex&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93)).

Answer (score 3):

You might look not only in Boost, but also into [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/) (its [Mutex](https://macchina.io/docs/Poco.Mutex.html) class) or [Qt](http://qt.io/) (its [QMutex](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmutex.html) class).

If you target only POSIX [pthreads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/), writing your own mutex class above its standard [mutexes](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#Mutexes) is doable and has been done a lot of times.

However, switching to C++11 is probably the best approach in 2017. Notice that *recent* [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) are supporting many (embedded, or tablet/laptop/desktop/server) processors.

<sup>(so it might worth the effort - or money - to get somehow a recent GCC or Clang, perhaps by compiling these compilers from their source code, or paying someone to do that work)</sup>

You should explain what computer (processor, operating system if any, available memory) you are targetting. Even if POCO or Qt or Boost can be compiled in C++03 mode, they might not fit on a tiny embedded processor (e.g. some Arduino).

Comment: Even in 2017, there still are platforms (i.e. embedded), where unfortunately there may not be C++11 compliant compiler. Anyway, switching to (at least) C++11 whenever possible is surely the best approach.

Comment: But *recent* GCC and/or Clang/LLVM can target a lot of processors (including in the embedded world), but of course, not all of them. BTW, on those platforms without any possible C++11 today, I would guess that no suggested solutions (Boost, POCO, Qt) would work painlessly.

Comment: Sure thing, but "a lot" does not mean "all" ;-)

Comment: Poco explicitly supports C++03 compiler (or did as of 1.6)

Comment: Yes, but I guess it might be too big to be *practically* compilable on *small* weird embedded systems (Arduino like). My point is that the OP should give more context to his question.

Comment: Rolling out your own mutex and condition variable classes is quite simple.

Comment: It depends for whom, and on which target computer. If only 100 bytes are remaining available in ROM, it might be a big challenge.

Answer (score 3):

Use pthreads on posix (most Unices) systems. On Windows, your best bet are CriticalSections.

Comment: More info: in the Win32 API, "mutex" is inter-process synchronization, and "critical section" is inter-thread (but not reaching outside the current process)